# Why does my apache health check thread terminate

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

I am running a reverse proxy with httpd on an ec2 t2.xlarge instance running amazon linux 2. The healthcheck thread runs as the same pid unless the status of the instance changes but after a certain amount of time with the same status the thread dies and the health checks stop running.  Any ideas why this is happening? It seems to happen when I am testing disabling the primary, by setting its firewall to block connections.

```
ProxyHCExpr ok2 {%{REQUEST_STATUS} =~ /^[2]/}
<Proxy balancer://archive>
#First is main and second is swap
    BalancerMember http://172.31.43.140:8888  connectiontimeout=12 timeout=24 hcmethod=GET hcexpr=ok2 hcuri=/gwt/status keepalive=on
    BalancerMember http://172.31.9.8:8888  status=+H
   ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
</Proxy>
```

This is paired with proxy pass configured to preserve host and nocanon is used. On launching the server I get only warning messages about heartmonitor and mpm modules. Any ideas what is causing the problem?